# Is using metadata navigation and filtering a way to bypass the list/library threshold

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, list-view-threshold, metadata-navigation

I have a document library inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013 enterprise server. and the document library contain a cusotm column of type drop-down named "ch". currently the document library contain 6,000++ documents, while the threshold inside our farm is set to the defualt which is 5,000. 
Currently inside the "All items" view i am sorting the items using the ID, so end users are able to view all the documents without getting any error. but if they try to do a column-based filter or column-based sort using any of the columns such as the "ch" they will get this error, since the list exceeds the threshold and the list does not have any indexed column:-
[image]

Today I enabled the metadata navigation and filtering site feature, and inside the document library i added the "ch" to the list's Metadata Navigation's Key Filters as follow:-
[image]

Now after doing so, end users were able to do the filtering based on the "ch" column inside the navigation columns, but they will get a message "Display only the newest results below", as follow:-
[image]

so i am not sure what happened , but can i simply say that using metadata navigation inside a list is a way to bypass the list threshold? now i know that adding a column to the metadata navigation inside a list, will add it to the "Indexed Columns" automatically. but in my case i was able to filter using the "ch" directly after enabling the Metadata Navigation (before the full crawl happen) + as i know if we already has a list which exceed the threshold (as in our case), then sharepoint will not be able to index the column as the list already exceeds the threshold.. 
so i am not sure if using metadata navigation and filtering inside our document library will allow us to bypass the list threshold? or still we have a threshold, but in this case how end users where able to filter based on the "ch" column then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using metadata navigation and filtering a way to bypass the list/library threshold. In the metadata navigation settings, “Automatically manage column indices on this list” is selected by default. The supported fields will be created as indexed column in the list.

When indices are created automatically, queries are allowed for lists that have more items than the list view threshold.

However choice field cannot be created automatically and we need configure custom indices manually.

Reference: [Configure metadata navigation for a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-a8ddfcd1-a486-4e0f-b1b1-f10ca79fa9bc)

Comment: @Hallofiona_MSFT as i mentioned before, that indexes could NOT be the reason that we are able to bypass the list threshold. as i mentioned in my question, that directly after enabling the metadata navigation and adding the "ch" column inside it, end users were able to filter based on the "ch" column. while we need to run a full crawl for sharepoint to create the index. also if we have a list which already exceeds the threshold (as in our case), and we add an index to it, then sharepoint will not be able to create any index for the list... so i do not think that indexes which got added for us

Comment: @Hallofiona_MSFT .. is the reason for allowing end-users to bypass the threshold. also and most importantly if i disable the metadata navigation and i keep the "ch" column inside the list's "Indexed Columns" , then end-users will face the threshold error again if they try to filter/sort the items using the "ch" column-based filtering/sorting..

Comment: any feedback on my above comments?thx